Issue about simplify dirac delta function
When I trying to simplify a dirac delta equation, I got the following result. The result confused me. How can I make the second equation output true
In[372]:= Simplify[x*DiracDelta[x] == 0]
Simplify[(x - R)*DiracDelta[x - R] == 0, 
  Assumptions -> {Element[x, Reals], 
    Element[R, Reals]}]
Out[372]= True
Out[373]= (-R+x) DiracDelta[-R+x]==0



To be more specific: actually the first behavior is (arguably) a bug, and it can cause serious problem, see the linked post for more info.
